# Multiple CSS Classes on a Single Element issue

Tags: css

I'm using a combination of two classes on a `span` element.

Both look like they're working by themselves... Together they're not.

```
.black {color:black;}
.size_14 {font-size:14px;}


<span class="black size_14">my text is not black..neither large</span>
```

I tried changing the `size_14` class name for another one (`large`) and in this case it is working.

**Is `size_14` an invalid class name?**

**SOLVED**

I was overriding the behaviour with

```
.article_text_div .size_14 {color:#6D6E71;}
```

But thanks to this mistake I discovered It's better(?) not to use underscores inside class names

Double thanks

Luca

Comment: `size_14` is a perfectly valid class name. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names but browser support is spotty.

Comment: Please show the complete page. If you've typed them together like what you've shown, they'll never work.

Comment: Your code worked for me - http://jsfiddle.net/N26ee/

Comment: Hi Luca. Out of curiosity, on which browser?

Comment: Not browser depending is very cross browser!..

Comment: [Not 100% true!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/underscores_in_class_and_id_names#Support_realities)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That example seems to work fine. There must be another rule that is overriding your change. Check the CSS with Firebug or a similar inspector, it will tell you exactly which classes are being used and overridden.

Answer (score 2):

Underscores are [not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Underscores_in_class_and_ID_Names) in class names and ID's. Support is mixed across the board. I would remove it or replace it with a dash.

Comment: That's from 2001, and is talking is about browsers like IE5 and Opera 5.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd be inclined to try the following, but without seeing the rest of the code it's difficult to tell if it'll make a difference..

```
.black{color:black;}
.size-14, span.size-14{font-size:14px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore, article in above comment was written in 2001. All latest browser supports use of _. But most developer prefer to use "-" for class names.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZsR4A/embedded/result/

Works as expected in IE, FF, Chrome. Make sure your size_14 has higher specificity.